# Possible generalizations of combinatorial species to arbotrary infinite sets

Tags: combinatorics, category-theory

It is well-known ghe notion of Joyal's combinatorial species. In his treatment, Joyal assumes finiteness. In fact he works with the groupoid of finite sets. The underlying idea is to capture the notkon of a structure on s finite ground set and to work "combinatorially" with. Ok, finiteness is essential for the Joyal's purposes.

However, one may consider the family of set partitions of an infinite set, or set-theoretic/algebraic/topological on infinite sets. Why does not exists a generalization of combinatorial structures dealing with these cases. Clearly, in such possible generalization, it is not possible to work with generating functions. But, actually, some othef techniques may be given. Why it has never been done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138518/generalization-of-analytic-functors where I was wondering the same

As for why, I don't know the exact answer, but after all this time I know that the features of the category of bijections of finite sets (e.g. being traced) are essential for some of the theory -as an example, the category of [virtual species](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124892/on-the-category-of-virtual-species) does not exist if you define species over $Bij(<\lambda)$ for a cardinal bigger than $\omega$.

Furthermore, a hint for why the category of species is so fundamental is that $Bij(<\omega)$ has the universal property of the free monoidal category on a singleton. $Bij(<\lambda)$ should then be the free category with a structure like a monoidal one, where you can tensor together, associatively (but what does it mean exactly now?), at most $\lambda$ objects, and you have a unit.

These kind of structures are elusive and way more unnatural: sets, and complete categories have it (the monoidal structure is a functor of every arity ${\cal C}^\lambda \to \cal C$ you might need); modules over a ring carry a similar structure more or less "by accident" (because you're representing the functor $N\mapsto\text{Bil}(\prod_{i\in I} M_i,N)\cong \hom_R(\bigotimes_{i\in I}M_i,N)$). I am not aware of other compelling examples.